# How to display Open Graph custom namespace data on a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-opengraph

I have lots of data for various objects in my custom namespace on Facebook. How do I display that data on the Facebook page?

In other words, if I have a custom type Apple, with the properties...

String name

String color

Boolean sour

...and I have the requisite meta tags on my Open Graph page, that are recognized by the Facebook Linter, how do I get those properties to display on the actual Facebook page, say in the Info tab (**not just as posts to the timeline or to the users who liked that page**)?